# PHP - Is there a way to go from switch case to default?

Tags: php, switch-statement, case, default

is there a way to go from switch case to execute what is in default?

```
switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {

    case 'edit':
        if (isset($_REQUEST['id']) {
            doSomething();
        else {
            goToDefault();
        }
        break;
        
    case 'list':
        ...
        break;
        
    default:
        doDefaultStuff();
        break;
}
```

In the example, I want in the first case's else to go execute what is in default of switch.

Is that possible, or should I use different approach?

Comment: Yes, IMHO you should use a different approach. Just because an id you might need for your `edit` action might not be set, does not all of a sudden make this into any _different_ action, like the default action. If you want to do some generic error handling in that default part - then I’d rather have my “real” cases set a flag to indicate whether there was any error or not, and then check on that flag _after_ the switch statement.

Comment: You could put the 'edit' case just above 'default', and remove the 'break' (if you have only one case like that of course) ; or do a 'if'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `goto`, but I wouldn't recommend that.

```php
$action = 'edit';
$id = null;
switch ($action) {

    case 'edit':
        if ($id) {
            doSomething();
        } else {
            goto default_action;
        }
        break;
        
    case 'list':
        break;
        
    default: 
        default_action: echo "doing default stuff";
        break;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/X71e8

You can use `switch(true)` instead:

```
switch (true) {
    case $_REQUEST['action'] === 'edit' && isset($_REQUEST['id']):
        doSomething();
        break;
        
    case $_REQUEST['action'] === 'list':
        // ...
        break;
        
    default:
        doDefaultStuff();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Everytime goto is used, somewhere a kitten will die.